# ExpandoObject Property Name Chapter Not Working

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm trying to learn ADO.NET and i figured out something like "ExpandoObject" which is really useful.

```
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from Products [p]", connection);

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();

        datatable.Load(reader);

        dynamic products = new List<dynamic>();

        for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            products.Add(new ExpandoObject());

            for (int v = 0; v < datatable.Columns.Count; v++)
            {
                string column_Name = datatable.Columns[v].ColumnName;
                object value = datatable.Rows[i].ItemArray[v];

                products[i].column_Name = value;

            }
        }

        reader.Close();

        connection.Close();

        listBox1.Items.Add(products[1].ProductName);
```

I'm using Northwind database by the way. "column_Name" and "value" part is working flawlessly. Error part is "products[i].column_Name = value;". I want something like
"products[1].ProductID = 1" at there. How can i do that. Thanks.

Comment: Please give more information - what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExpandoObject` also implements `IDictionary<string, object>`.  For this interface the keys are the property types and the values are the values of that property.  Using this interface you can get/set values of an `ExpandoObject` using properties determined at runtime, not compile time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> nextItem = new ExpandoObject();
    for (int v = 0; v < datatable.Columns.Count; v++)
    {
        nextItem[datatable.Columns[v].ColumnName] = 
            datatable.Rows[i].ItemArray[v];
    }
    products.Add(nextItem);
}
```